# JSON - deserializing client class using Gson

Tags: java, google-app-engine, serialization, gson, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a problem deserializing a class using Google Gson. This problem has afflicted me for days and I cannot find a solution.

I have created a simple test case, this is the minimal working subset of my class:

```
import java.util.Date;

import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();

    Gson gson = builder.create();

    DateTest dt = new DateTest(new Date());
    String j1 = gson.toJson(dt);
    System.out.println(j1);
    DateTest dt2 = gson.fromJson(j1, DateTest.class);
    System.out.println(dt2);

}

static class DateTest {
    @com.google.api.client.util.Key
    private final DateTime date;

    public DateTest(Date dt) {
        this.date = new DateTime(dt);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return date.toString();
    }
}
}
```

This produces the desired output.

Serialised to:
    {"date":{"value":1381503448717,"dateOnly":false,"tzShift":60}}
Deserialized back to:
    2013-10-11T15:57:28.717+01:00

However, the class I am trying to serialise is automatically generated from a Google App Engine class using "Generate Cloud Endpoint Client Library" (meaning I am not able/willing to modify it but also that this class IS serializable/deserializable to JSON with jars I have in the classpath - see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android ).

After a lot of testing I found out the problem is the auto generated class "extends com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson" - if you change the code to:

```
static class DateTest extends com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson{
```

the serialisation succeeds (with the same output) but deserialising fails with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.util.LinkedHashMap to Test$DateTest
at java.lang.Class.cast(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:643)
at Test.main(Test.java:17)
```

Android seems to be giving a more detailed output, the problem is any non basic class attribute fails.

My question is - how can I modify my deserialization code so the deserialization is successful? What am I doing wrong?

As my project is able to deserialise the same JSON object from the network please be aware I will not accept any answer on the kind "try using another JSON library".

Comment: Please clarify which class you are actually trying to serialize/deserialize.

Comment: I am trying to deserialize DateTest, the version extending GenericJson

Comment: Can you bring us an example of the JSON that you're not able to deserialize?. I ran your test case and, indeed, everything works well. So the problem must be in the JSON that gives you Google.

Comment: Sorry if I have not been clear. Serialising "static class DateTest {" given in the example succeeds, but if I modify the class to "static class DateTest extends com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson {" the deserialisation fails. Clearly the class is designed to be deserialisable, it get deserialised successfully by Google code I just do not know how - I am clearly doing something wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a weekend of digging through Google code, I found the following code which solves my problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    GsonFactory factory= new GsonFactory();

    DateTest dt = new DateTest(new Date());
    String j1 = factory.toString(dt);
    System.out.println(j1);
    DateTest dt2 = factory.fromString(j1, DateTest.class);
    System.out.println(dt2);

}
```

Hope this will help other people in the future.

Comment: where did you get the GsonFactory from ? what maven artefact version of gson ? tried 1.7.2, 2.2, 2.2.4 and did not find that class - only the GsonBuilder which is not helpful.

Comment: @Vasile - com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory in google-http-client-gson-x.xx.x.jar (I believe it is in the standard AppEngine Android client libraries)

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles upon this, let me expand on why this works. The original code is using `Gson` whereas this new code is using `GsonFactory`. The key difference is that Gson's package name is `com.google.gson.Gson` whereas GsonFactory is `com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory`. Or in other words, its package starts the same as `GenericJson` class Endpoints uses. Therefore Google must use slightly different serialisation rules between the two Gson classes. (In my code, I noted that longs were saved directly as longs in Gson, but as Strings in GsonFactory.)

Comment: You are amazing. You solved the exact problem I had (serializing objects from Endpoints).

Comment: This is what I needed!      "Comment high five"